# Using a macro with a defined body in C++

Tags: c++, macros

I am learning C++ and have come across this code snippet and cannot understand the syntax:

```
.
.
#define DO_MUTEX(m, counter) char counter; \
for (counter = 1, lock(m); counter == 1; --counter, unlock(m))

#define mutex(m) DO_MUTEX(m, UNIQUE_COUNTER(m))


int main(){

   mutex(my_mutex) {

    foo();

   }  
   .
   .
   .
}
```

is `foo()` a callback? why does the `mutex` macro in main have a body?

Comment: `foo();` is simply a function call. Ignore the rest of this; it's horrible, and studying it will not help you learn C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker that didn't really help, I like to know what this syntax means

Comment: `mutex` is the name of a macro. `mutex(my_mutex)` is an invocation of that macro with the argument `my_mutex`. Once that substitution is done, the compiler gets to look at the result. So if you **really** want to know what it's doing (again, it's horrible code), expand the macro yourself, and stare at the resulting code.

Comment: I suppose I should add: those curly braces are not part of the macro. They're text that comes after the macro, so they're still there after the macro is expanded. Essentially, it's `for ( ... ) { }`, where the `for ( ... )` comes from expanding the macro.

Comment: @PeteBecker so at the end it will look like this? `for ( ... ) { foo(); }`, basically the body of the macro is simply the body of the for loop in the other macro?

Answer (score 1):

> is foo() a callback?

`foo()` is a function or a macro.

> why does the mutex macro in main have a body ?

Probably because the `for` loop in `DO_MUTEX` doesn't.

---

To better understand the code, try to expand the macros manually.  Then you get something like :

```
int main()
{
    auto &counter = UNIQUE_COUNTER(my_mutex);
    for (counter = 1, lock(my_mutex); counter == 1; --counter, unlock(my_mutex))
    {
        foo();
    }  
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I don't know what `UNIQUE_COUNTER()` expands to, so I'm guessing it returns a reference to some sort of counter or integer type.

Comment: You haven't expanded the macro correctly. `counter` is an argument to the macro. Its name won't appear in the expansion.

Comment: @Pete Becker, is it possible to expand it correctly without knowing what `UNIQUE_COUNTER()` expands to ?  I'm declaring `counter` as a placeholder, so this should work sufficiently to understand what the code does in lieu of more information.

Comment: `UNIQUE_COUNTER(x)` has to expand to an **identifier**, not a value. It’s type is `char`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, *yes* - otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to create a reference for it, like I did.

Comment: Oh, I see. But it’s used as the name of a local variable of type `char`. It’s not an external name.